# Convert a UTF-8 without BOM xml file into ISO 8859-1

Tags: xml, visual-c++, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have an xml file UTF-8 encoded without BOM. In an hex editor it gives : `3c 3f 78 6d`

I buffer my xml file and add the BOM at the beginning:

```
char* BufferEncoder = (char*)malloc(3);
memset(BufferEncoder, 0, size);
for(int i=0;i<3;i++) BufferEncoder[i] ^= 0xaa;
BufferEncoder[0]=(char)0xef;
BufferEncoder[1]=(char)0xbb;
BufferEncoder[2]=(char)0xbf;
// concatenate into a new Buffer containing old xml and the BOM
```

I tried then to convert from UTF-8 with BOM to ISO 8859-1 using these lines of code :

```
int size = WideCharToMultiByte(28591 /*ISO-8859-1*/, 0,  pBuffer, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);
if (size>0)
{
    char* pBuffer2 = (char*)malloc(size);
    memset(pBuffer2, 0, sizeNew);
    WideCharToMultiByte(28591, 0,pBuffer,-1, pBuffer2, size, NULL, 0);
    // .........
```

This code is not yet tested. Do you think that this is the best solution? Any idea or advice is welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I hate asking this question, because the answer is universally terrible: Why do you feel you have to convert the text from UTF-8? Also, if WideCharToMultiByte does what I think it does; you're using the wrong function. UTF-8 isn't a wide character encoding; and ISO-8859-1 isn't multibyte.

Comment: Thank u for answering. My xml file is generated by another tool (TLC Simulink) and I have no control on it. The load function of IXMLDocument can't load an xml UTF-8 without BOM containing special caracter.. for that reason i have to convert it to UTF-8 with BOM and then to ISO 8859-1 else it will not work.. What's the correct function so? :)4

Comment: If that is the case; IXMLDocument is irreparably broken. Use a different XML handling tool. In case this has not been made clear to you; the correct way to handle an XML document without an XML declaration stating the encoding and yielding no other hints as to what the encoding might be is to treat it as UTF-8 without BOM. Any tool that does differently is Doing It Wrong™, and needs to be shunned and shamed; and perhaps drawn and quartered if time and sensibility allows.

Answer (score 1):

As I touched on in my comment: I think this line of thought necessitates a few questions right back at you, so to speak:

1. Why are you doing this conversion in the first place?
2. Do you actually know what `WideCharToMultiByte()` does?

I'll freely admit that I myself am not entirely clear on exactly what `WideCharToMultiByte()` does; but I'm going to go right ahead and assume that it converts a string of wide characters to a string of multibyte characters. From a quick glance at the documentation, it seems as if it does this into a new buffer, returning the length of the new string.

Which is all well and dandy. The problem is that UTF-8 is *not* in fact a wide character encoding; and ISO-8859-1 is *not* a multibyte encoding. UTF-8 *is* a multibyte encoding; but that doesn't really help you much in this case.

My advice; then, is that you read up on character encodings; especially about the differences between UTF-8 (multibyte) and UTF-16 (wide).

I also suggest that you find a different interface for whatever you are trying to do that actually accepts UTF-8 strings; because any interface that requires ISO-8859-1 strings, especially when dealing with XML, strikes me as being insanely legacy-y, bordering on completely insane.

Of course, had you actually stated what you were trying, on the whole, to achieve; more specific advice could be given.

**Edit:** If I understand your conundrum correctly, the issue is that you are getting a correctly formatted and encoded XML file that may contain characters outside of the ASCII range (U+0…U+127). If this is the problem, using ISO-8859-1 in any way, shape or form will set you up for the mother of all headaches down the road:

## Encoding Issues

If the text file can contain *some character* outside of the ASCII range, then it can conceivably contain *any character* outside of the ASCII range. And while UTF-8 can represent *any character*, this is not true of ISO-8859-1.

In other words; your best case scenario if you stick to interface that mistreat encodings is irreversible lossage of information; worst case scenario is crashage and burnage.

My point is: Don't coddle the broken interface, and Never Don't Use UTF-8.

Comment: My problem is more simple I think: The xml file generated by Simulink if encoded UTF-8 without BOM could contain special caracters and then IXMLDocument couldn't load it. New version of Simulink propose now a xml file generated with an ISO 8859-1 and which is loaded correctly. My problem now is how to load my old xml files (utf8 without BOM) and load them by converting them into iso 8859-1. Thank you for answering.. I am not a specialist in XML and encoding..

Comment: @Jawhar: To reiterate: Never Don't Use UTF-8. I cannot stress this point enough. Thanks to some terrible choices made in the past based on assumptions that turned out to be brain-blightingly wrong (such as the cost of storage space and transmission of data) the whole issue of character encoding is a total mess, but Unicode, and UTF-8 in particular is a shining beacon of hope in this terrible tangle of terribly troublesome terribleness. The issue is that the interface you are using is broken, and you need to learn how to identify and handle the correct interface and tools for XML handling. 600.